# "Fulfill online orders from this location" option status through Location API

Tags: php, shopify

I have 3 locations in my `shopify` store, but in one of them the option "Fulfill online orders from this location" is disabled. When I retrieve locations list though Inventory API https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/location#index it doesn't return any information about the "Fulfill online orders from this location" option status.
Is there a different API where I can fetch this info? Or could you please add an appropriate field in locations for Inventory API responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you probably have not assigned inventory to that location? Items in inventory dictate fulfillments, based on levels. If you read up on InventoryLevels, you can see how fulfillments from locations for items is setup.

Note: the explanation from Shopify may seem excellent to them, but to me it is a tough slog to understand how their system actually works. Experiment will tell you all the problems.

My two cents to you is that you should not focus at all on the Location endpoint of the API, and instead, spend your time figuring out your InventoryItem and InventoryLevel setup issues.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/inventorylevel
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/inventoryitem